# SimConnect C# - Autopilot Master returns always 0 or false

Tags: c#, .net, windows, simulation

I'm developing a program using SimConnect in C# to retrieve information about the autopilot in MSFS2020. When attempting to check whether the autopilot is turned on or off, I consistently receive 'false' or 'zero.' I expect to retrieve a '1' or 'true' in the 'autopilotMaster' property from SimConnect when the autopilot is active. I have a suspicion that I've made a mistake, but I can't pinpoint it.

**My question is:**
How can I correct retrieve autopilot master from SimConnect in C#?

```cs
SimConnect simConnect = new SimConnect("Managed Data Request", IntPtr.Zero, WM_USER_SIMCONNECT, null, 0);

simConnect!.AddToDataDefinition(RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation, "Title", null, SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE.STRING256, 0, SimConnect.SIMCONNECT_UNUSED);

simConnect.AddToDataDefinition(RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation, "Plane Altitude", "feet", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE.FLOAT64, 0, SimConnect.SIMCONNECT_UNUSED);

simConnect.AddToDataDefinition(RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation, "AUTOPILOT MASTER", "", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE.INT32, 0, SimConnect.SIMCONNECT_UNUSED);

simConnect.RegisterDataDefineStruct<AirplaneInfo>(RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation);

simConnect.RequestDataOnSimObject(DataTypes.AirplaneInformation, RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation, SimConnect.SIMCONNECT_OBJECT_ID_USER, SIMCONNECT_PERIOD.SECOND, SIMCONNECT_DATA_REQUEST_FLAG.DEFAULT, 0, 0, 0);

simConnect.OnRecvSimobjectData += RetrieveData;

simConnect.ReceiveMessage();
```

This is how I get the information:

```cs
private static void RetrieveData(SimConnect x, SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA data)
{
    if (data.dwRequestID == (uint)RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation)
    {
        var info = (AirplaneInfo)data.dwData[0];
        
        // This property is always 0 or false
        var autopilotMaster = info.autopilotMaster;
        
        // This property behaves as expected.
        var title = info.title;
    }
}
```

Here is a overview of my struct and enums:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct AirplaneInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public String title;
    public double altitude;
    public int autopilotMaster;
};

public enum DataTypes
{
   AirplaneInformation = 1
}

public enum RequestTypes
{
    AirplaneInformation = 1
}
```

I already tried to change my struct to:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct AirplaneInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public String title;
    public double altitude;
    public bool autopilotMaster;
};
```

I also tried to change the values when defining a new data source and I tried different kind of datatype:

```cs
simConnect.AddToDataDefinition(RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation, "AUTOPILOT MASTER", "bool", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE.INT32, 0, SimConnect.SIMCONNECT_UNUSED);
```

But the results are still the same.

I already I try to read the documentation and tried the following pages:
[AIRCRAFT AUTOPILOT/ASSISTANT VARIABLES - AUTOPILOT MASTER](https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Programming_Tools/SimVars/Aircraft_SimVars/Aircraft_AutopilotAssistant_Variables.htm#AUTOPILOT%20MASTER)
[PROGRAMMING SIMCONNECT CLIENTS USING MANAGED CODE](https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Programming_Tools/SimConnect/Programming_SimConnect_Clients_using_Managed_Code.htm)

I expect to retrieve '1' or 'true' when the autopilot is turned on.

**Edit:**
I added a new boolean property "SIM ON GROUND". This boolean property is now working correctly. However, the result of the Auto Pilot is not. I need to find out what is happening there. Maybe I'm using the wrong variable "AUTOPILOT MASTER".

```cs
simConnect.AddToDataDefinition(RequestTypes.AirplaneInformation, "SIM ON GROUND", "Boolean", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE.FLOAT64, 0.0f, SimConnect.SIMCONNECT_UNUSED);

//The new version of the struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct AirplaneInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public String title;
    public double altitude;
    public double onGround; // 0 is false, other value is true
    public double autopilotMaster;
};
```

**Edit 2:**
I was using the airplane FBW A32NX. I saw that AUTOPILOT MASTER is always 0 in the debug menu. This is working normally with a default Airplane from MSFS2020. This was the reason why it was always 0 in SimConnect.

**Edit 3:**
I'm going now to develop with the default airplane A320 of MSFS2020. Then everything will work with the SimConnect. Otherwise you need extra software to read the custom properties.

Comment: A note on your "edit 3": no you don't, you just need to be able to load the simconnect .dll file in C#, and then call the correct functions? However, the FBW A32NX is an _open source_ project, so if it's sending the wrong values, help everyone out by asking about that [on their issue tracker](https://github.com/flybywiresim/aircraft/issues).